# regexp specify counter in character class

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create regexp to find duplicated commas, like here:

```
baz(uint32,,bool)
```

For now my pattern is : `\w*\([\w\[\],?+]+\)`

which is not working.

How can one specify quantity for items in character class?

Comment: `[,]{2,}` Two or more consecutive commas. See [Java RegEx Quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify a number of occurrences inside a *character class* since this construct is used to define a specific character type. Inside `[...]`, the `*`, `+`, `?`, `{1,2}` are treated as literal symbols.

If you need to just match several comma separated words inside parentheses, use

```
\w*\(\w*(?:,\w*)*\)
```

or with obligatory first word:

```
\w+\(\w*(?:,\w*)*\)
  ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wLLJcC/1) (or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/wLLJcC/2)).

In Java, use `String re = "\\w+\\(\\w*(?:,\\w*)*\\)";`.

**Pattern details**:

- `\w*`  - 0+ word chars
- `\(` - one literal `(`
- `\w*` -  0+ word chars
- `(?:,\w*)*` - zero or more *sequences* (the `(?:...)` and `(...)` define sequences or alternative sequences if `|` is used inside the groups) of a comma and 0+ word chars
- `\)` - a literal `)`

Comment: (?:...) - specific for Java? Can't find any doc for it.

Comment: See [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon). Also, [Non-Capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). It is a widely accepted construct in NFA regex (non-POSIX one).